dynamic programming min path grid sum
I recently found a frustrating error in my code. I have two solutions for finding the minimum path sum using dynamic programming (DP). The first solution, which I wrote, doesn't seem to work, even though the logic seems perfect. Here's my code:
class Solution {
    public int minPathSum(int[][] arr) {
        return f(arr.length-1, arr[0].length-1, arr);
    }

    public int f(int i, int j, int[][] arr) {
        if (i < 0 || j < 0) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) return arr[0][0];
        int up = arr[i][j] + f(i-1, j, arr);
        int left = arr[i][j] + f(i, j-1, arr);
        return Math.min(up, left);
    }
}

However, I found another solution online that works:
class Solution {
    public int minPathSum(int[][] grid) {
        int m = grid.length-1;
        int n = grid[0].length-1;
        return find(grid, m, n);
    }

    public int find(int grid[][], int m, int n) {
        if (m < 0 || n < 0) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if (m == 0 && n == 0) return grid[0][0];
        return grid[m][n] + Math.min(find(grid, m-1, n), find(grid, m, n-1));
    }
}

The only difference between my solution and the working solution is how we return the result. In my solution, I used up and left to store the result of recursive calls with the current path value, and later chose the minimum path. However, in the working solution, it's all done in a single step. What's the difference between these two? Please clarify my doubt.

Please be more specific about the defect of your first implementation. What exactly does not work? Is there an error message, does an actually generated result differ from an expected result? Please also include a description of the computational problem to be solved by the implementation. Furthermore, to my impression, both of the implementations don't use dynamic programming but explicit recursion; please clarify.
